# EasyAdmin : redirect to the page of Crud controller with custom actions

Tags: symfony, easyadmin

I have a MessageCrudController and I made a custom action with easy admin to import some messages templates with an API

Now I want to be redirected to the list of my messages in my dashboard, but I don't know how to do that, It's my first custom action

there is page where I want to be redirected :

[image]

there is what I tried :

MessageCrudController

```
public function fetchMessages()
    {
      some logic to get my messages...
      return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('admin', [
                'action' => 'index',
                'entity' => 'MessageCrudController',
            ]));
    }
```

Actually, I tried this return, and it redirect me to the homepage of my dashboard, and not to the messages page

someone have an Idea to how can I be redirected to my message page of my dashboard? thanks

Comment: What is that "message page"? How did you configure that in the first place?

Comment: Maybe https://symfonycasts.com/screencast/easyadminbundle/custom-controller#generating-an-admin-url could help?

Comment: Nico Haase, "message page" is the page of the list of my messages in the dashboard of easyadmin

Comment: Please add all clarification to your question by editing it

Comment: I edited with a screen of my message page

Comment: What hve you tried to resolve the problem? Did the link help in any way?

Comment: Yes the answer of Evgeny Ruban and your link with the variable $targetUrl Helped me to solve my issue, thanks you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `'entity'` key seems to be wrong for url generator properties.

I prefer to get `AdminUrlGenerator` service from the container and generate urls using it:

```
$this->container->get(AdminUrlGenerator::class)
    ->setController(MessageCrudController::class)
    ->setAction(Action::INDEX)
    ->generateUrl();
```

This way much more easy to avoid mistakes here.